# Ag Grid React - save a data from Ag Grid table to useState()

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

when I set in:

const[data, setData]=useState()

value from table(Ag Grid React)using getSelectedRows(), I discover that, the last selected value in table do not apear in data :(

What could I do to select and add the data to useState() at the same time?

The code above:

`const onSelectionChanged = (e)=>{ const selectedData = e.api.getSelectedRows(); setData(selectedData); console.log(data)`